# Facebook and Twitter missing in ShareMediaTask

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a WP8.1 app, when I try using ShareMediaTask to share a picture it shows me a list of apps where I will share the picture. Facebook, Twitter and other apps like Whatsapp are not included in the list; it shows me only share to OneNote. Taking note that I debug from device with Facebook and Twitter installed on it.
If someone could help me thankfully.

This is my simple code :

```
ShareMediaTask shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
shareMediaTask.FilePath = fileName;
shareMediaTask.Show();
```

Do I have to add something ?!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at [Sharing content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871374.aspx) for Windows Runtime apps. Sharing is different between Silverlight and Runtime apps.

Here is a basic sample on [how to share files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871371.aspx):

When you are ready to share:

```
DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
dataTransferManager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager, 
    DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.ShareStorageItemsHandler);
```

And then populating the data:

```
private async void ShareStorageItemsHandler(DataTransferManager sender, 
    DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "Share StorageItems Example";
    request.Data.Properties.Description = "Demonstrates how to share files.";

    // Because we are making async calls in the DataRequested event handler,
    // we need to get the deferral first.
    DataRequestDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();  

    // Make sure we always call Complete on the deferral.
    try
    {
        StorageFile logoFile = 
            await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Assets\\Logo.png");
        List<IStorageItem> storageItems = new List<IStorageItem>();
        storageItems.Add(logoFile);
        request.Data.SetStorageItems(storageItems);       
    }
    finally
    {
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

Only apps that implement sharing will show up in the list. Currently Twitter and Facebook have not released an app that implements sharing.

For more information of receiving shared content, see [this doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871369.aspx).

Comment: Sorry but Facebook and Twitter have released an app that implements sharing, if you have Windows Phone 8.1 hold tap an image from Gallery select share then Facebook, Twitter options will show to you

Comment: Yup, took another look at your question and updated my answer

Comment: Where I have to write the file I would share ?!

Comment: An error is shown to me at this line :
DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
"Specified method is not supported"